# Unit test rest service without specifying URL

Tags: servicestack

Using servicestack, there are examples of unit testing using types, etc.  Here is an example: 
[GetFactorial](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Examples.Tests/GetFactorialTests.cs)

I would like to test my REST style service with a test similar to the above.

Here is an example REST unit test [FileService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.Tests/SyncRestClientTests.cs#L118)

Notice how in the PUT unit test, the Path argument has to be specified in the URL text instead of in the class argument.  Another example is [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestIntro/RestIntro.IntegrationTests/IntegrationTests.cs), where we have perfectly good request models that have to be translated into the URL.  For testing, I would like to get away from having to build the arguments in the url and use a system similar to the one above like this:

```cs
var response = restClient.Put<FilesResponse>(new Files { TextContents = ReplacedFileContents, Path = "README.txt" });
```

or

```cs
var singleCustomer = restClient.Get<Customer>(new Customer {Id=1};
```

Is this possible?

Then there is the [DirectServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/WebServicesTests.cs).  Would that help? In the end, with servicestack, we get to write services and they can be called from many different type clients - I would like to write my unit test like that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decorate your DTOs with the route variable and use ServiceStack's "New API" then it can discover the routes automatically. You can get away with writing very minimal code and still get a strong typed rest API.

Your code could look something like this:

```
Customer singleCustomer = restClient.Get(new Customer {Id=1});
```

See https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api

In response to your comments, your DTO needs to adhere to the IReturn interface:

```
[Route("/customer/{Id}")]
public Customer : IReturn<Customer> {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

The IRestClient interface below will now be able to work with your DTO without specify the type since it is expecting an IReturn object.

```
public interface IRestClient 
{
   TResponse Get<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> request);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I had hoped. However if you look, that is not supported.  The Get() only takes in the string of the url.

Comment: @WayneBrantley It is supported once your Request DTO implements `IReturn<T>`

Comment: @mythz - how can that be supported?  The restclient interface does not take any request parameters.  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Service/IRestClient.cs  If I am confused, can you provide an example?  I would expect to do restClient.Get<MyReturn>(new Customer {Id=1});

Comment: @WayneBrantley I've updated the answer to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: @WayneBrantley Check the interface again, it uses the API methods that accepts `IReturn*`.

Comment: In trying that, I get object reference not set to an instance of an object in Common.StringExtensions.CombineWith.  I guess I will have to get a repo of that.  @mythz - instead of implementing the interface, why can I not just do restClient.Get<MyReturn>(new Customer {Id=1}); ?

Comment: @WayneBrantley Because I want to force users to provide the type info in 1 place (i.e. on their Request DTO marked with `IReturn`) rather than all the call-sites. It also reduces support costs as users wont send me bug reports when trying to send any object instead of the Request DTO.